# Android TV: How to customize left navigation panel of android TV using Leanbak?

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

Currently I am working an android tv application project and my navigation panel is showing text and icon when it is in expanded mode like -

[image: expanded]

When navigation panel is collapsed it showing a vertical bar with just color and no icons or something is showing.

But I am trying to achieve this kind of design when navigation panel is collapsed -

[image: collapsed]

Now my question is is this achievable using leanback and if possible how can I implement it?
Any kind of hints, tips or reference will be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This type of functionality is not supported in Leanback. And I too searched the solution for it everywhere but didn't find anything useful. So I ended up writing a Fragment that behaves like the sidebar navigation and works with RowsSupportFragment through an interface for exchanging KeyPad Events.

When in Expanded State -> Menu Icon & Menu Names are shown.

When in Collapsed State -> Menu Icons are shown.

check out this repository [TVNavigationMenu](https://github.com/Arpit0492/TVNavigationMenu)

[image: Navigation Closed]

Comment: i have used your Example can we do this  with a dynamic category  with left nav can you please help me this

Comment: hi, @MARSH drop me your mail id. let's connect over that.

Comment: Hi @Arpit let me know if you are able to send me a mail I  need help with this. Thannks

Comment: Hi @Arpit J   Thanks for helping me can you suggest how to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try **Navigation Rail** from **Material Design**. It is not a same thing but can get you somewhat close to your desire behavior or an alternative solution.

Here is link: https://m2.material.io/components/navigation-rail

Answer (score -1):

try this [repo](https://github.com/khaleeljageer/) it's fine.let's try this it  will help
[image: sample image]

[image: sample]